# Find the largest segment within a queried range?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, data-structures, segment-trees

We are given $k$ segments $(s_1,e_1),(s_2,e_2),(s_3,e_4),...,(s_k,e_k)$ where $s_i\le e_i$.
Now we are given a query interval $[L,R]$ to find the largest segment $(s_i,e_i)$ contained within $[L,R]$.

By the term **largest** we mean among all the segments contained within $[L,R]$ return the one whose $e_i-s_i$ is maximum.

And by term **contained** we mean $L\le s_i\le e_i\le R$

I am looking for an approach to answer the query in $O(\log n)$ where $n = \max(R_i)-min(L_i)$

after some precomputation/tree-building etc costing no more than $O(k~\log n)$. So if I have to answer $q$ such queries my overall complexity should be $O(k~\log n\ +\ q~\log n)$.

All the above values are integers.

My thoughts:

Note that overall complexity I require is for online query ie lets just focus on solving for one query for now.
For offline queries I found a solution [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71459)
There it's mentioned that it can be solved for online too using [Fractional cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_cascading) but doesn't quite explain it in detail.

The other related problem where I am trying to draw ideas from is [this](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5541).
For anyone who thinks they have something in mind please do refer these two resources.

Comment: Have you looked at segment trees?  interval trees?

Comment: @D.W.Yes i am expecting a segment tree solution. Can you add it to the tags if you have privilege.

Comment: Is it possible to answer the query in $O(\log k)$?

Comment: @JohnL. it should be but overall complexity should be $O(n\ log\ n)$ or $O(k\ log\ n)$ .  I think it will need Lazy propagation with segment tree.

Comment: Although it doesn't meet your time requirements, your problem can be easily solved using range trees if you are willing to pay a preprocessing time of $O(k \log^2 k)$ and a query time of $O(\log^2 k)$.

Comment: @Steven sure go ahead. Fractional cascading that the blog was talking about would result in two logs too I guess.

Comment: @vanessamartins I posted an answer. If you are familiar with layered range trees, it also discusses how to achieve a time complexity of $O(\log k)$.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/153628/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73381614/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved in $O(\log k)$ time per query by augmenting layered range trees. Let me start with a slower solution first, and then I discuss how the time complexity can be improved.

Consider each segment $[s_i, e_i]$ as a $2$-dimensional point $(s_i, e_i)$ with an associated weight $w_i$. In your case $w_i = e_i - s_i$, but the following solution works in general.

A 2D-range tree consists in a logarithmic-height outer binary-search tree in which each leaf represents the $x$-coordinate of a point, which can be thought of as a trivial interval. Each internal vertex $v$ having $u$ and $z$ as children represents the interval of the $x$-axis going from the left endpoint of $u$'s interval to the right endpoint of $v$'s interval.

A vertex $v$ of the outer tree points to an array $A(v)$ storing exactly the points whose $x$-coordinate lies in $v$'s interval. This array is sorted according to the points' $y$-coordinate.

Let $k$ be the number of points in the range tree. Given an interval $[x_a,x_b]$ of the $x$-axis and an interval $[y_a, y_b]$ of the $y$-axis, we can navigate the outer tree to find a set $V$ of $O(\log k)$ vertices such the union of their intervals covers exactly $[x_a,x_b]$. In your case $x_a = y_a = L$, $x_b = y_B = R$.

For each vertex $v \in V$ we can further binary search the array $A(v)$ to find the range of indices $i_v, j_v$ of $A(v)$ containing the points that simultaneously have their $x$ coordinate in $[x_a,x_b]$ (from the choice of $v$) and their $y$ coordinate in $[y_a, y_b]$ (from the binary search).
Each binary search requires $O(\log k)$ time. Therefore, the total time spent so far is $O(\log^2 k)$.

To find the point with the largest weight, the trivial solution would be to inspect all points $(s_i,e_i)$ in the discovered ranges and return the one maximizing $w_i$, however this would be too costly since there can be many candidates. Instead, we can build a satellite range minimum query (RMQ) oracle $\mathcal{O}(v)$ attached to each $A(v)$. A range minimum query oracle preprocesses an array $B$ and, given two indices $i$ and $j$, is able to report an index $h$ such that $i \le h \le j$ and $B[h]$ is maximized. These oracles can be built in linear time and support constant-time queries. For each $A(v)$ consider the array $B(v)$ such that the $i$-th entry of $B(v)$ is the weight of the $i$-th point in $A(v)$ and then build a RMQ oracle $\mathcal{O}(v)$ on $B(v)$.

You can now query each oracle $\mathcal{O}(v)$ with $v \in V$ using the indices $i_v, j_v$ to find the point with maximum weight. Querying all oracles requires $O(\log k)$ time, and hence the overall time spent is $O(\log^2 k + \log k) = O(\log^2 k)$ per query.

To reduce the query time further, you can use the cross linking idea from fractional cascading. This is a known technique and the resulting data structure is known a layered range tree. Essentially, you are able to simultaneously find the set $V$ and, for each $v \in V$, all the indices $i_v$ and $j_v$ in time $O(\log k)$ (instead of $O(\log^2 k)$). This brings down the overall time needed to answer a query to just $O(\log k)$.

The building time of a layered range tree with two dimensions and $k$ points is $O(k \log k)$, and so is the time needed to build the satellite RMQ oracles (since the overall size of all the arrays is also $O(k \log k)$).

---

[Here is a C++ implementation](https://gitlab.com/steven3k/range-trees) of a 2D Layered range tree that can be augmented by defining custom node types via dependency injection. The relevant file is `TwoDLayeredRangeTree.h` and is heavily commented.

In the same repository there is an implementation of a RMQ oracle via jump pointers. The building time of such an oracle is $O(n \log n)$ (more complex oracles having a linear building time exist) and the query time is $O(1)$ as long as `std::bit_width` runs in constant time (modern processors can report the number of leading 0s in a single instruction).

Finally, there is also an an example program defining a custom range tree node that uses the above RMQ oracle and (essentially) solves the problem mentioned above (more precisely it shows how to find the lightest point in a specified 2D query range).

A compiler supporting C++20 is required.

Comment: It would be great if there is a sample implementation in Python or C/C++.

Comment: Boost's icl library is supposed to have all nlog n trees. If not from scratch should it be easier to implement using boost's ICL? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @JohnL. See the updated answer :)